# Angular Tour of Heroes : problems with inMemory Web API

Tags: angular, angular-cli, in-memory-database

I'm following the famous Angular tutorial, Tour of Heroes, but I'm struggling with one step.

On the [sixth course, HTTP](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6), we are using a tool made to mimick API calls to an API.

I think I followed all the steps, up to [this point](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#get-heroes-with-httpclient) where it is stated the folliwing :

> Refresh the browser. The hero data should successfully load from the mock server.

But I may have missed something : the http calls all give http 500 headers with the error being `Object(...) is not a function`.

Have I missed something about creating a route ? It seems odd to me that inMemory wep API does not seem to need a route.

My test code is available here : https://github.com/MarcBrillault/tourOfHeroes/tree/StackOverflow

Comment: If the server is returning a 500, it sounds like the error may lie in your server side code, not your client side angular code

Comment: I have literally NO server side code, because as I understod it, inMemory Wep API is made to capture these calls ad answer them (With this configuration file : https://github.com/MarcBrillault/tourOfHeroes/blob/StackOverflow/src/app/in-memory-data-service.ts)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is what I had to do in order to get your code to run after pulling it from your repo.

First, downgraded to `angular-in-memory-web-api@0.5.4`. This means changing the version in the *package.json* to `^0.5.4` and running `npm i`.

```
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.5.4",
```

I have heard here and there that some were having trouble with the 0.6.0 version of `angular-in-memory-web-api`, so this was the first step I tried.

According to [this](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#060-2018-03-22), `angular-in-memory-web-api` version 0.6.0 requires *Angular "^6.0.0-rc.0" and RxJS "^6.0.0-beta.1"*.

So, the downgrade should get you moving forward with the tutorial. Feel free to move to the Angular and RxJS versions above when you are ready.

Then, I needed to make these changes in the *hero.service.ts*.

Added this import:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

Change this:

```
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    return Observable.of({id: 1, name: 'test'});
}
```

to this:

```
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    return of({id: 1, name: 'test'});
}
```

All was working after this. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with the 0.6.0 version, i downgraded to 0.5.4 and this solved my problem, thank you

Comment: @Torai They tied 0.6.0 to the new 6.0.0-rc version of Angular. So, if you are not on that version, it will not work. Glad this helped you.

Comment: ah ok, i didn't  know that, thank you for this information

Comment: Thanks, I was using Angular 5 and after installing correct version of the package and setting dataEncapsulation: true in app.module.ts, it was loading the data. Thanks.