# Problem with HttpClientInMemoryWebAPI in Tour of Heroes

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

I've been doing the Tour of Heroes tutorials again since I'm coming off of a 4 month hiatus from Angular. Everything was going fine until I hit the http section. Specifically [the HttpClientInMemoryAPI section](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6). From what I've found searching it sounds like its a compatibility issue. I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470299/angular-tour-of-heroes-problems-with-inmemory-web-api) as well as [this one](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/issues/189) and tried reverting to version 0.5.4. I also tried deleting the node_modules directory and doing a npm install (I did make sure the ver for the InMemAPI stayed at 0.5.4 before running install). Most of the other articles I found were geared towards Angular 2 so I didn't spend much time trying those. The error I'm currently getting is:

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/http-backend.service.d.ts(2,75):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
>   node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/http-backend.service.d.ts(3,10):
>   error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Development/Working/tour-of-heroes/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"'
>   has no exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/http-client-backend.service.d.ts(2,10):
>   error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Development/Working/tour-of-heroes/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"'
>   has no exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/http-in-memory-web-api.module.d.ts(2,28):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
>   node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/interfaces.d.ts(1,10): error
>   TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Development/Working/tour-of-heroes/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"'
>   has no exported member 'Observable'.
>   node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.

I hope I've done enough research not to get flamed for asking this, if not please at least point me to a good url as the 2 articles I posted above seem to be the most relevant and recent.

Thank you all, your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend going to an older version of the library if possible. Are you targeting an older version of Angular?

The current version of the InMemoryWebAPI targets Angular v7, so if you are using Angular v7 you should use the current version of the InMemoryWebAPI (v0.7)

Confirm that your package.json *does* contain `@angular/http`. This *should* have been added when your app was created. Mine package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",         // <-- This should be here already
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    // ...
```

So even though we now use `HttpClientModule` in the code:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

We still pull in `@angular/http` in the package.json file. (If you use the Angular CLI, it should already put this in for you.)

Comment: My current Angular Version is 7.1. I did the import as you stated in my app.module.ts file, however, I just noticed a message as I reinstalled the latest version of the InMemWebAPI module which reads:
npm WARN angular-in-memory-web-api@0.7.0 requires a peer of @angular/http@>=6.0.0 <8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
---
I was under the impression, incorrectly apparently, that the http module was included in the initial setup of the project when I created it with the cli. Do I need to manually install a different http module for the InMemoryWebAPI?

Comment: Something is definitely odd. I'll update my answer with more information.

Comment: That did it. I used the "ng new angular-tour-of-heroes" command to create the project and don't recall manually removing anything from the package.json file so I'm not sure why it was missing, but it builds and runs now. Also, thanks a lot for all of your work. I learned a lot from your PluralSight courses. Some of the best out there.